# Switching Object Oriented mysqli to Procedural

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function build_calendar($month, $year){
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ems');
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(event_date) = ? AND YEAR(event_date)=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $month, $year);
    $bookings = array();
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $bookings[] = $row['event_date'];
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
```

I wrote out this code as a fix for fetching booked dates from my database and displaying them on my calendar but I'm not an OOP guy yet and I'd love to have this syntax in Procedural format which I still understand better.

I already tried

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ems');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(event_date) = ? AND YEAR(event_date)=?";
    $get_dates = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_dates)){
        $booked_dates[] = $row['event_date'];
    }
```

But this returns an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result

Comment: Your procedural code doesn't prepare the statement, look into `mysqli_prepare` so you can properly replicate the OO code.

Comment: I'd use this as an opportunity to learn OOP syntax instead...

Comment: @NigelRen I tried using the Php docs to learn the `mysqli_prepare` but I got confused more when I tried following the steps in the doc.

@ADyson I guess I have to learn OOP syntax if I want to use it. I just started learning procedural last week I didn't know there was a different approach until after the end of the course. 

Thanks for the tips guys

Comment: `I tried using the Php docs to learn the mysqli_prepare but I got confused more when I tried following the steps`...in this case you literally would just replace the commands in the OOP version you've been given with the procedural equivalent of each one as shown in the manual. You can just do it line by line. But I wouldn't bother - in the long term OOP is much easier to understand and results in much more maintainable code. It's worth the effort to understand that instead.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. There's absolutely no reason to use procedural mysqli style. It was designed only to help people migrate from PHP 4 code. You should not use it in a new code base.

Besides, using mysqli in OO-style does not make your code OOP and you don't even need to know OOP to use mysqli in OO-style.

If you want to know what is the difference between procedural and OO-style mysqli, it's only the different name of the function and you must pass the object as the first argument.

This means that these are equivalent:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(event_date) = ? AND YEAR(event_date)=?");
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(event_date) = ? AND YEAR(event_date)=?");
```

Your function converted to procedural mysqli still looks the same:

```
function build_calendar($month, $year)
{
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ems');
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(event_date) = ? AND YEAR(event_date)=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $month, $year);
    $bookings = array();
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $bookings[] = $row['event_date'];
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
}
```

However, by learning mysqli you are learning a lot of bad practice due to the bad tutorials out there. I would highly recommend learning PDO. If you really want to suffer with mysqli then you can at least simplify the code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ems');

function build_calendar(mysqli $mysqli, $month, $year): array
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(event_date) = ? AND YEAR(event_date)=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $month, $year);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

$bookings = build_calendar($mysqli, 1, 2020);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dharman will definitely check out the PDO doc. The php tutorial I paid for only taught in mysqli I guess it's time to get an upgrade.

Comment: I would consider getting a refund if you paid for a tutorial teaching you mysqli. That sounds really bad

Comment: It was on udemy. I guess I just ended up having bad luck while starting out a new language. Glad I got good advice before getting all confident about being a php programmer.